# Update target in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have a `target` on my `recyclerView`
When I move on to this task, I call the `updateTarget()` method:

```
private fun updateTarget(name: String, description: String) {
        val map = mapOf("name" to name, "description" to description)
        databaseReference?.child("targets")?.child("users")
            ?.child(uid.toString())?.child("targets")?.child(targetGuid)?.updateChildren(map)
    }
```

But after I change the `name` with the `description`, and click update,
it does not change the existing `target` but adds a new one without the `guid` field.
And it turns out the following structrure:

[image]

`-LmjBTkVXhmXaqL0b4RG` here redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the value of your `name` property, please use the following lines of code:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val targetsRef = rootRef!!.child("targets").child("users").child(uid).child("targets")
val query = targetsRef.orderByChild("guid").equalTo("-LmjBTkVXhmXaqL0b4RG")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            ds.child("name").getRef().setValue("The New Vadim Morozov")
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

Comment: `setValue` is unresolved reference. Mb i need cast to `Target`?

`Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
@InlineOnly public inline operator fun <V> MutableMap<in String, in TypeVariable(V)>.setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: TypeVariable(V)): Unit defined in kotlin.collections`

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I just added a call to `.getRef()` function. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: cool, it's working, thanks.
we couldn't do it with the method: `updateChildren()`?

Comment: Good to hear that :) Yes you could do that but in that case you could only update a single element. In this case, you can update multiple. Glad I could help.